# Scalable Inference Server for Object Detection

Tags: django, bigdata, gunicorn, object-detection-api, inference

I have created a Django service (nginx + Gunicorn) for object detection models.

For my case i have 50+ models with resnet 50 based back bone.

**Server Machine Specification:**

1. 16 CPU
2. 64 GB Ram

I have pre-loaded all the models in my service. I am running 20 inference requests in parallel.

But issue i am facing that Gunicorn intermittently restarts any worker out of 8 workers  when inference is running and it is not due to time out. it starts to reloading the model in service again. Due to this my inference requests are failing.

I have notice that might be due to server's all cpus are utilised to 100%.

Can you please suggest the solution or other way to run inference as service ?